# Request filter mechanism in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, filter, interceptor, http-redirect

Is there a mechanism in React to filter/interceptor request. 
Eg. For specific URL, i want to do some flag check and depending on flag I want to do 404, 301 redirect. Else 200 OK normal page.

Comment: Make wrapper client on top of http client and make all of your calls using that wrapper. Then you can add whatever you want in that.

Comment: Thanks Vipin. Are u referring API fetch? I want to do it for a normal page URL.